# Debug Assertion Failes

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing a c++ code using OpenCv integrated in Visual Studio 2010..
I am following this tutorial :

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/06/load-display-image.html

but when I run the code, I got this error message:

Debug Assertion Failed 
Program: ...cuments\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1\x64\Debug\test1.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\fopen.c
Line: 54

Expression: (file != NULL)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat im = imread("C:/Users/Ruaa/Pictures/aa.png");
    if (im.empty()) 
    {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("Image", im);
    waitKey(0);
}


'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Ruaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test1\x64\Debug\test1.exe', Symbols loaded.
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv1\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_core245d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv1\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui245d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_a44e1fc257f685f6\comctl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100.dll', Symbols loaded.
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100.dll', Symbols loaded.
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...cuments\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1\x64\Debug\test1.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\fopen.c
Line: 54

Expression: (file != NULL)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded.
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The program '[4984] test1.exe: Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

this is the call stack:

```
msvcr110d.dll!fopen()  + 0x23 bytes 
    opencv_highgui245d.dll!000007feea737ea8()   
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for opencv_highgui245d.dll]    
    opencv_highgui245d.dll!000007feea73a725()   
    opencv_highgui245d.dll!000007feea73a5f1()   
>   test1.exe!main()  Line 10 + 0x3d bytes  C++
    test1.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x19 bytes    C
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
    ntdll.dll!0000000077752ca1()
```

Comment: That's not the call stack.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I can't find it, I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Comment: To see the call stack proceed as follows: run your program with the debugger (Debug->Start debugging). Once it has hit the assert, do Debug->Windows->Call Stack.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is EMPTY!!

Comment: What happend if you click on the "Retry" button onc ethe assert has been hit ? You should be able to see the call stack then.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I got the call Stack, but I can't copy its content

Comment: @MichaelWalz I added the call stack

Comment: Click on the 1st line of the call stack, then click on the last line of the call stack while holding the Shift key pressed, then right click on one of the selected lines and choose "Copy". And then update your question with the call stack

Comment: Just to be sure, run `mspaint C:/Users/Ruaa/Pictures/aa.png` (in the run dialog or a command line), does it work ? Also, does the assert triggers in a release build ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz it says It is not found!!!!

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't know any more.

Comment: And if you build in release configuration do you still get the assert or "Cannot load image" ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz it doesn't work in release mode.. it doesn't recognize openCv libraries

Comment: Try removing the `d` at the end of your libs : `opencv_highgui245` instead of `opencv_highgui245d`

Comment: @Antoine I removed the 'd' from the libs, and build it in debug mode and it works!!!

Comment: @roa.tah I'm not Michael...

Comment: @Antoine sorry!!
LOL !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. Your file `C:/Users/Ruaa/Pictures/aa.png` doesn't exist, you should try with an existing file
2. You use the debug version of OpenCV's libs, remove the `d` at the end of `.lib` / `.dll` files, like `opencv_highgui245d` => `opencv_highgui245`, this will prevent the assert, make it faster, and you rarely need to debug *inside* OpenCV

Comment: Still pretty strange that it asserts if the file doesn't exist. `imread` with an inexistant file should return some error code or whatever but not assert deeply in the OpenCV library.

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely something fishy going on, but it's hard to tell what! Either the string passed to `fopen` by OpenCV is bad/null or MSVC's `fopen` is too strict in debug mode ?